# Failed to connect to the existing server farm located at the specified database server and database name

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

[image]I am trying to add a new SharePoint 2013 web front end and I am getting this error message when I try to add the config database by using SharePoint configuration Wizard.

Error message :

Failed to connect to the existing server farm located at the specified database server and database name. The database name is not a valid configuration database.

I attached some pictures from the ULS log , event log and error message.

I will appreciate any help,

*Mohammad*enter image description here
[[image]][[][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inrIP.png)1]

Answer (score 1):

Does the server added to same domain as SQL Server?

If other SharePoint server works fine, check the firewall for current server.

Follow [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36615.sharepoint-troubleshooting-cannot-connect-to-database-master-at-sql-server.aspx) to troubleshoot.